# How to detect a input signal of a non standard keyboard button ? Asus ROG laptop

Tags: linux, keyboard, script, signal, hardware-detection

I am looking for a way to trigger some stuff when I press the 'ROG' key on my keyboard which is **Asus specific**. 
When I run `showkey` it doesn't output any value.

Do you have any idea if there's a way to interact with it in a GNU/Linux environment ?

I am running Kubuntu 18.04, on Asus Strix Hero II laptop GL504G.

Comment: Very likely the ROG key is managed by the Embedded Controller (EC) of your laptop. You can try `evtest` on all sources, but if `showkey` doesn't output anything, chances of finding anything else on the input layer are low. Another option is that it produces an ACPI event.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a couple of trails to follow. However I didn't have luck with these, I also tried using ```xev``` without success.

Comment: `xev` of course won't help at all, because it relies on the kernel input layer. The blame lies on the Laptop producers who don't open their hardware specs, and all do those extra keys differently.